# CSS- jQuery - scroll one div to left while expanding another div at same time to width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have html page/ screen split into 4 main parts/ divs. Header, footer, main body and left vertical navigation panel. the navigation panel width is 20% and main body div is 80% width of screen. I have button in navigation panel to hide and display. so when user click this, it hide navigation panel and make main-body width to 100% of screen and vise versa. I have achieved this functionality using jQuery but its not smooth, what I mean by this, on click navigation panel slides to left but same time it make main_body disappears until navigation panel complete scroll to left.

I want this functionally to run smooth i.e. main body div increases its width same time navigation panel is scrolling to left.

http://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/73c8o8tq/

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".NavigationpanelIcon_Wrapper").click(function () {

    $('#NavigationBlock').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);

    $('.Main_body_Right_Wrapper').css('width', '100%');
  });
```

});

### HTML ASP.net-MVC - Razor

```
<div id="body_main_wrapper">

        <div id="NavigationBlock" class="Navigation_Left_Pannel_Wrapper">

            <div id="Navigation_panel_sideBar">  

                <div class="NavigationpanelIcon_Wrapper">
                        <span class="_blank_glyphicon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                        </span>
                </div>

                <div class="NavigationpanelText_Wrapper">
                    <span class="navigationpaneltext">
                        Available Functions
                    </span> 
                </div>

             </div>

            <div id="Navigation_list_wrapper">
                @{Html.RenderAction("DisplayFunctionsList", "Dashboard");}
            </div>

        </div> <!--end Navigation_Left_Pannel_Wrapper-->

        <div class="Main_body_Right_Wrapper">

            @RenderBody()

        </div> <!--end Main_body_Right_pannel_Wrapper-->

</div> <!--end body_main_wrapper-->
```

Comment: A demo would be great for this, that way we could test it and show you a demo of it after a fix. Think about creating a demo in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Animating the width of *.Main_body_Right_Wrapper* should do the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".NavigationpanelIcon_Wrapper").click(function () {
    var duration = 1000;
    $('#NavigationBlock').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, duration);
    $('.Main_body_Right_Wrapper').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, duration);
  });
});
```

**Edit:** I forked @AwRak's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/18omvagy/2/) to illustrate it.

Comment: this functionality is fine but problem is it hide main_body while  NavigationBlock is sliding to left!

Comment: It should not, or I got the question wrong. The width is animated at the same time. When the sliding is at 50% progress, the width main_body is still only at 90% of its container width. I don't get why it should be hidden. I updated my answer is a Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate this quickly [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3hxjvf99/)
You could wrap both elements and float the sidebar to the left while giving it a fixed position size then give the main body a  `margin-left` that equals to the sidebar navigation width.. then on click when you hide the sidebar and just reset the main body's margin ? 
Let me know if it's not working for you..